# Tree view ( 2 level ) inside a Combox box with second level as radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, combobox, jstree

I need to show 2 level hierarchical data inside a combobox using jquery.The first level should be collapsible and second level should contain radio boxes to select one of the options. Something similar to this image.Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: offtopic, because you are asking to recommend the software library... read the rules: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic